# Using Ionic command gives update message, then gets stuck at '[INFO] Not automatically updating your CLI.'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

Command used: `ionic cordova build android --prod`

Reply:

> ? The Ionic CLI (local version) has an update available (3.9.2 => 5.2.7)! Would you like to install it? No
>
> [INFO] Not automatically updating your CLI.

...And it gets stuck here and does not proceed

Tried looking for solution everywhere. I don't want to update my local ionic version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are using Node version higher than node 8.

1. Uninstall your current Node version. I guess it should be Node 10+?
2. Download and Install Node v8.11.3
3. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
4. Relaunch your code
5. Run 'npm serve'

This should work. Worked for me. been about it for 3 days now. Ok now